# no xamarin.forms BlankApp in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, visual-studio-2017

I have just installed Visual Studio 2017 community addition. Furthermore, i have installed Xamarin Community edition. Initially i thought i would have to use Xamarin Studio in order to create cross platform apps. But later on, i figured it out from the internet that Xamarin Studio is only installed in MAC OS. In windows, Xamarin is installed in form of Visual Studio's extension instead. After completely installing Xamarin on my Windows 10, i opened Visual Studio and i didn't saw **"BlankApp (Xamarin.Forms Portable)"** under Visual C#/Cross-Platform tab. Instead there were only couple of Class Libraries and a UI Test App there.

How can i figure out the way to create Xamarin Cross-Platform on my visual studio 2017 community edition? Am i missing some extensions, or is there any update required ? Please help.

Comment: Hi @Hyder, have you solved this? We have the same issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

File > New > Project > Installed > Templates > Visual C# > Cross-Platform
Select Cross-Platform
Select Cross Platform App (Xamarin.Forms or Native)

[image]

New App Dialog Opens
For template select "Blank App"
For Code Sharing Strategy Select "Portable Class Library (PCL)"
Click OK, and you are good to go

[image]

Comment: I don't get Protable Class Library and I have all components installed is this normal? I only see a .Net option is this the PCL now?

Comment: New stuff is now.NET Standard.  It replaces PCL.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this site in section "Creating your first app".

More information in:
http://motzcod.es/post/158155898027/setting-up-vs-2017-for-xamarin-dev

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS NOT A DIRECT ANSWER**, I tried lots of options from installing, uninstalling, modifying but I can't find "bank app xamarin forms".

**SO WHAT I DID**, Installed visual studio 2015 and found "that bank app xamarin forms" there.